# Django ORM object.related.id vs object.related_id after used select_related('related')

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

Let's suppose that we have this models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ....
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

class Order(models.Model):
    ....
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

After used select_related for query like that `Order.objects.filter(...).select_related('product')`, is there any performance difference between `order.product.id` and `order.product_id`?

Comment: There will be no performance difference as we pre populated the `product` using `select_related('product')`.

Comment: There will be no performance difference, since if we `.select_related('product')`, Django will load the relevant `Product` object, and add that as attribute to the `Order`.

Comment: The modeling is however a bit *odd*, since this means that for an order, you can only order one (type of) `Product`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks a lot. I wrote this for explain what I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a difference, but not database-related. There is always a performance cost when accessing any object field in Python, so for specified example:

```
order.product.id
```

Will need to fetch 2 different attributes from 2 different object, first it needs to fetch `product` attribute from `order`, then it needs to fetch `id` from `product`.

```
order.product_id
```

Will need to fetch only 1 attribute: `product_id` from `order`.

This is purely about fetching the correct data from the memory, which is not cost-free in Python, it doesn't involve any IO to database or other resources. This cost, in a lot of the cases is very small and can be omitted, as there will be probably far more similar operations like this in your code.

Comment: that was the answer I was looking for, thank u so much.